# Python3 - argparse switch and file

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

Hi I am trying to implement a small program which takes in 1 flag `-s` and a file

I would like to do the following:
When I want to sort:

```
$./my_program.py -s someFile.txt
```

when I dont want to sort:

```
$./my_program.py someFile.txt
```

Here is what I tried:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='A tutorial of argparse!')
parser.add_argument("-s", default=False, type=bool, help="Is the DAG sorted? If yes, use the \'-s\' flag")
parser.add_argument('filename', help="Your database file")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

When I tried to run it from commandline I tried this:

```
my_program.py -s SortedDB.txt
```

I get:

```
error: the following arguments are required: filename
```

If I do this:

```
my_program.py -s filename SortedDB.txt
```

it works

or this:

```
iota_ledger_task.py iotaSortedDB.txt
```

it goes to the non sorted case (expected behavior), works.

What may I be doing wrong here?

Comment: try `action="store_true"` instead `type=bool`

Comment: @furas Thanks, put it as the answer and I will mark it as so

Comment: Your `-s` definition is the default `store` action, which expects an argument.  So the following string is given to that, rather than to `filename`.  And `bool` is not a useful `type`.  The `bool` function in Python doesn't convert words like `yes/now/true/false` into boolean values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `action="store_true"` instead `type=bool`

Documentation: [Actions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action)